# Can we cross-post Examples between Topics in Docs?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I don't think this is possible now so I'm flagging it as a feature request.

In PHP, we had a request for a Security topic

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/topic-requests/1181

In particular this comment struck me

> It's super-big, but distributing the content all over the place doesn't help anything either. It's more helpful when you see it all at once… can then give it people to read "this are the most important security problems"

He's right. But there's two topics that SQL Injection fits into:

- Databases
- Security

It seems silly to have two examples. Could we have a way to take an example and cross post it to another topic?

Comment: You have a way: just cross-post it. On the other hand, maybe they need to be slightly adapted to each topic?

Comment: @Trilarion Not exactly. The idea of Security would be a roll-up list of topics. And having two sections covering the same topic sort of defeats the purpose of SO in general

Comment: Inside Security topic, you can _link_ to databases for more detail; but it should be mentioned at both places.

Comment: @Machavity If the examples do not need to be adapted, then we truly need a mechanism to show examples from another topic. However, my experience is that quite often they need to be slightly adapted. But if not than I fully agree that with this feature request.